# CSV not working if I put some extra space. Getting list index out of range error

Tags: python, csv

I am new in python and I am trying to getting `CSV` data using python code.
Every thing is working first time,But when I edit my `.csv` file then an error occured says:

```
File "D:/wamp/www/optimizer_new/new_code/optimal_lineup.py", line 310, in get_player_list
    if (int(row[4]) == -1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am just putting a extra space inside my `.csv`

here is my sample code:

```
def get_player_list(possible_name):

    file_name = ""
    if (len(possible_name) > 0):
        file_name = possible_name
    else:
        file_name = 'basketball_data2.csv'

    player_list = []
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            if (int(row[4]) == -1):
                #print("Skipping %s" % (row[0]))
                continue

            name = row[0]
            pos_p = get_possible_positions(row[1])
            c = row[2]
            v = row[3]
            my_p = player(int(c) / 100, float(v), name, pos_p, int(row[4]))

            player_list.append(my_p)
            '''
            name = row['Player Name']
            c = row['Salary']
            v = row['FP']

            pos_p = get_possible_positions(row['Pos'])

            player_list.append(player(c, v, name, pos_p))
            '''
    return player_list
```

My CSV contain these columns:

```
Player Name,Pos,Salary,FP,Keep/exclude
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does your CSV contain?

Comment: I Just update my question

Comment: Not enough. Can you provide data - both before and after you've edited it so that we can attempt to replicate your issue?

Comment: That may be what you *intend* for each row to look like, but that error message indicates that at least one row only has 3 commas, so that `row[4]` does not exist. I suggest catching the `IndexError` and printing the offending row before re-raising the exception.

Comment: Also, how are you editing your CSV file? If you're using a European version of Excel, your commas might have been changed to semicolons...

Comment: Really Don't know how to share CSV file here

Comment: I just found problem,It's removing the commas when I save the CSV file,How can I get this fix?